# relativeLayout crisis

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

So I want a linearLayout at the top of the screen that has 2 buttons, a linearLayout at the bottom that also has two buttons and a listView in the middle. The problem I'm running into is that the bottom linearLayout gets covered up if the listView gets too big. I'm telling the listView to wrap_content as it's layout_height because I want to do that...but I almost positive thats the reason the bottom linearLayout isn't showing. 
Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/importClasses"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
        </Button>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Title"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical|center"
             >
        </TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addClasses"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
      </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/classList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/topLayout" >

    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/classList"
         >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Assignments"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/flashCards"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `classList` to be above `bottomLayout` and below `topLayout`.

Also set `bottomLayout` to `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, and `topLayout layout_alignParentTop="true"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/importClasses"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Title"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical|center"
         >
    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addClasses"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
  </LinearLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/classList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topLayout" >

</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Assignments"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/flashCards"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That works, Thank you. So weird why I have to align it with parentTop and bottom though...Guess I'll just have to remember that, thanks!

Comment: Sure.  The reason you need to assign the top and bottom is because the RelativeLayout items rely on anchors.  Without anchoring the layout items to specific locations they will all start at the top left of the screen and just overlap each other.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but you may need to change your `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout`.

And change the `layout_height` of your `ListView` to `0dp` and add `layout_weight="1"` to it.